# Multiplication of polynomials in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

I enter an array and the code should multiply this array by `(x^2 + 2*A*X + A^A)`.
for example an array `1, 3, 3, 1` should have answer `1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1` if `A = 1`. I have tried to write the code but I have no idea how I am supposed to multiply polynomials in C++.

> CODE

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int a, n;

std::cout << "Enter the Power n: "; //Power decides the size of array.
std::cin >> n;

std::cout << "Enter the number A: ";
std::cin >> a;

int arr_size = n + 1;       

int *array = new int[2 * arr_size];

std::cout << "Enter the array P(X): ";

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
{
    std::cin >> array[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";

const int x = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i] * x ^ 2;
    array[i] = array[i] * (2 * a*x);
    array[i] = array[i] * (a * a);

    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use std::transform() with a functor coding your function.

Comment: The `^` operator is *bitwise or*, not exponentiation. Just multiply `x` with itself. And of course, `Aᴬ` is not equal to `A * A`.

Comment: Oh and please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please edit your question to actually *include* a question. It's unclear what your problem is, what you're actually asking about.

Comment: I asked clear , how to multiply polynomials ? Whats so ambigous in it ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's the bitwise xor, probably autocorrect change?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // coefs before multiplying by powers of A
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,1};

    // make polynomial coefs vector
    int A = 1;
    const int as = a.size();
    int ap = 1;
    for(int ai = 0; ai<as; ++ai){
        a[ai] *= ap;
        ap *= A;
    }

    std::vector<int> b = {1,3,3,1};
    const int bs = b.size();

    // result vector
    std::vector<int> c(as + bs - 1, 0);

    // multiply vectors
    for(int ai = 0; ai<as; ++ai)
        for(int bi = 0; bi<bs; ++bi){
            c[ai+bi] += a[ai]*b[bi];
        }

    for(int cn: c)
       std::cout << cn << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an output array for this and properly multiply your results.

I'm considering that index = polynomial exponent (i.e. `[0]` is for `x**0`):

```
std::vector<int> array(arr_size, 0);

std::cout << "Enter the array P(X): ";

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
{
    std::cin >> array[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

std::vector<int> out(arr_size+2, 0); // We add two new coefficients

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    out[i+2] += array[i]; // bumps the coefficient for x**2
    out[i+1] += array[i] * (2 * a); // add the coefficient for 2ax
    out[i] += array[i] * (a * a); // Adds the coefficient for a**2

}
for(int coeff: out)
    std::cout << coeff << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a problem that you can solve with a `std::valarray`

I mean... if your `array` is

```
std::valarray<int>  array(arr_size);
```

next you can simply write

```
array *= x*x + 2*a*x + a*a;
```

Off topic suggestion: you're using C++11 so, please, avoid to manage directly your dynamic memory.

In your code you have allocated an array

```
int *array = new int[2 * arr_size];
```

but you haven't deleted it.

Use, when possible, standard containers (`std::valarray` but also `std::vector`) and when you have to manage dynamic memory, use smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, etc.).